# Istio installation on AWS using ELB TCP getting 504 timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, istio, gateway, nginx-ingress

i am fairly new to Istio - so far i have a k8s cluster (using kops) on AWS , behind ELB.

All traffic is routed via TCP.

[image: AWS listener config]

Ingress gateway service is configured as NodePort with following config

`istio-system   istio-ingressgateway                           NodePort    100.65.241.150   <none>        15020:31038/TCP,80:30205/TCP,31400:30204/TCP,15029:31714/TCP,15030:30016/TCP,15031:32508/TCP,15032:30110/TCP,15443:32730/TCP`

I have used 'demo' helm option to deploy Istio 1.4.0.
Have created gateway, VS and DR with following config - 
Gateway is in istio-system namespace, VS and DR on default namespace

```
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ingress-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway 
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 31400
      name: tcp
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - "*"   
---
kind: VirtualService
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: webapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:     
    - "*" 
  gateways:
    - ingress-gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: webapp
            subset: original
          weight: 100
        - destination:
            host: webapp
            subset: v2
          weight: 0
---
kind: DestinationRule
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: webapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: webapp
  subsets:
    - labels:
        version: original
      name: original
    - labels:
        version: v2
      name: v2
```

Service pods listen on port 80 - and i have tested via port forwarding - and are functioning as expected.
Although when i do curl on https://hostname externally i get a

```
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
```

i have enabled debug logging in the envoy - but dont see anything meaningful in the logs relating to the timeout.

Any suggestion on where i might be going wrong?
Do i need to add any service annotations relating to ELB in istio ingress gateway? 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you configure your cluster to use loadbalancer? From the screen I can see that you use NodePort in istio-ingressgateway but I assume you want to use loadbalancer. Check this [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports). If you want to use NodePort then you need to configure it as in above doc, if you want to use LoadBalancer your istio-ingress gateway service should have LoadBalancer type and should have an EXTERNAL-IP. Let me know if that help.

Answer (score 0):

I found few things which need to be fixed

### 1. Connect with loadbalancer

As I mentioned in comments you need to fix your ingress-gateway to automaticly get EXTERNAL-IP addres as in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports), for now your ingress is a NodePort so as far as I'm concerned it won't work, you can configure it to use with nodeport, but I assume you want the loadbalancer.

The first step would be to change istio-ingressgateway svc type from NodePort to loadbalancer and check if you get the EXTERNAL-IP.

> If the EXTERNAL-IP value is set, your environment has an external load balancer that you can use for the ingress gateway. If the EXTERNAL-IP value is  (or perpetually ), your environment does not provide an external load balancer for the ingress gateway. In this case, you can access the gateway using the service’s node port.

It should look like there

```
kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   172.21.109.129   130.211.10.121  80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP   17h
```

And then everything goes through the external-ip address which is 130.211.10.121

### 2. Fix your yamls

> Note, for tcp traffic like that, we must match on the incoming port, in this case port 31400

Check this example from [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/tcp-traffic-shifting/)

Specially [this part](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.4/samples/tcp-echo/tcp-echo-all-v1.yaml) with gateway, virtual service and destination rule.

You should add this  to your virtual service.

```
tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 31400
```

### 3. Remember about namespaces.

In your example, because it's default it should work, but if you create another namespace, remember that if gateway and virtual service are in another namespace then your need to show virtual service where is the gateway.

Example [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/)

Specially the part in virtual service

```
gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway
```

---

I hope it help you with your issues. Let me know if you have any more questions.